# Gamma_only case not implemented?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I am use Quantum espresso
I calculated scf and Bands but i can't caluleted Band_pp for ploting Band Structure.
[![enter image description here[image: ][1][1]]

[image]
[image]

Comment: The site allows you to place input files in ```code``` blocks. Please update the question to conform to that. This way someone can test your files.

Comment: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411/5

Comment: You have some problem with the input files. You shouldn't have the `&BANDS` block altogether. Also, I am guessing since you put the `K_POINTS` block before the `&ELECTRONS` block, it assumes a gamma-only calculations for which calculating band structure doesn't make any sense. In addition to converting the images to code blocks, also specify the name of the input files or state which input files for which purpose.